# Ammo Conservation for Plasma Weapons

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

Does the Ammo Conservation foundry project apply to plasma weapons?

It is not clear from the [description on XCOM Wiki](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Ammo_Conservation).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doubles the ammo capacity of all weapons.  This means less time reloading and thus more time killing enemies/setting up for overwatch/etc.  It is an excellent foundry upgrade.

Comment: Quick question related to that... after the research, does it automatically upgrade the existing items (for instance, the scopes becomes super-scope) or do I need to build the improved version of the item?

Comment: @vianna77 yes, it will automatically apply to all primary weapons going forward.